# Reduce large parenthesis or brackets

Tags: brackets

I am using `\left[` and `\right]` around a mathematical formula that has also an `\underbrace`.

```
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{Nc}{\left[\frac{\partial \dot{m}_{i}}{\partial z}\hat{h}_{i} + \dot{m}_{i}\underbrace{\frac{\partial \hat{h}_{i}}{\partial T}}_{c_{p i}}\frac{\partial T}{\partial z} \right]}dz  
\end{equation}
```

The brackets include also the underbrace and its text, which I do not want.

**How do I get them to be smaller?**

I am using

```
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}    
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{float}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
```

Comment: Use `\biggl[` and `\biggr]` instead of `\left[` and `\right]`. By the way, there's no need of `\limits` nor of bracing the formula after `\sum`: `\sum_{i=1}^{Nc} \biggl[...` is correct and simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @egreg suggests, you can force the size of the delimiters. I'll also suggest to use `\underbracket` (from `mathtools`) rather than `\underbrace` here: in my opinion, for small parts of formulae, \underbrace doesn't look too nice. With \underbracket, you can adjust line thickness and bracket height:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{3}
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{Nc}{\biggl[\frac{\partial \dot{m}_{i}}{\partial z}\hat{h}_{i} + \dot{m}_{i}\underbracket[0.4pt][2pt]{\frac{\partial \hat{h}_{i}}{\partial T}}_{c_{p i}}\frac{\partial T}{\partial z} \biggr]}dz
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is perfect, thank you! I have to install the `mathtools` package to use `\underbrackets`, but I actually like `\underbrace`, and I used it in other equations too. I'll see with my professors what they think.

Comment: In your documents, you can replace loading amsmath with loading mathtools, since the latter loads amsmath. It has many useful possibilities.